# how set background color for autocomplete box

Tags: angularjs, html

**I try to change background color but not working.**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 padding0">
    <div style="margin-left: 5px;">
          <small style="color: White;">To</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">                                       
        <autocomplete id="autocomplete" options="GetBusCities" place-holder="Enter City Name..." on-select="onSelectr"
          display-property="Name" input-class="form-control" clear-input="false"></autocomplete>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where did you try to change the background color at?  you aren't showing that here....

Answer (score 0):

That is because you don't have any label or data within autocomplete, So add label or any value within `<autocomplete></autocomplete>`, then you can change and see background color of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you are using autocomplete you can put attributes inside these classes:
body .ui-autocomplete {
  /* font-family to all */
}

body .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item .ui-corner-all {
   /* all <a> */
}

body .ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item .ui-state-focus {
   /* selected <a> */
}

for the hover use something like this:
.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper:hover
{
    border: none !important;
    background-color: #your-color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if its working , otherwise i will share some other solution.
Add some value in , then you can change and see background color of it.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: One Must have 50 reputation to comment.